# Почему не срабатывает запрос в базу?

Tags: php

Перебирая массив мне надо вносить данные в базу:

```
$i=time();
foreach ($data as $k => $value){
    if ($value[chek] == "on") {
        $i++;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_id`, `created`, `type`, `pair`, `price`, `quantity`, `amount`, `block_id`, `status`) VALUES ('$i', '$i', '$value[type]', '$value[pair]', '$value[price]', '$value[quantity]', '$value[summ]', '$value[block_id]', '$value[order_status]');";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    }
}
```

и это работает, строки в базе появляются. Но что-то внутри меня говорит мне, что не хорошо в цикле генерить запросы в БД, хоть явных противопоказаний к этому в документации нигде не видно. Но всё равно я делаю так:

```
$i=time();
foreach ($data as $k => $value){
    if ($value[chek] == "on") {
        $i++;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_id`, `created`, `type`, `pair`, `price`, `quantity`, `amount`, `block_id`, `status`) VALUES ('$i', '$i', '$value[type]', '$value[pair]', '$value[price]', '$value[quantity]', '$value[summ]', '$value[block_id]', '$value[order_status]');";
        $sqli .= $sql;


    }
}
mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);
```

И вот во втором случае уже не работает. Хотя если я сделаю

```
echo $sqli;
```

и вручную вставлю полученные данные в phpMyadmin, то всё вставляется корректно, строки добавляются.

Вопрос: почему если $sqli корректно сформирована и вручную добавляется в базу, то не добавляется скриптом через

```
 mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);
```

?

Comment: Mysqli_error посмотрите.... там вполне однозначно сказано почему

Comment: вот моё echo и вот мой mysqli_error: INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_id`, `created`, `type`, `pair`, `price`, `quantity`, `amount`, `block_id`, `status`) VALUES ('1539042216', '1539042216', 'sell', 'ETH_UAH', '10000', '0.00002390', '0.1529177', '4', 'открыт');
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_id`, `created`, `type`, `pair`, `price`, `quantity`' at line 1
Синтаксической ошибки я не вижу и эти данные пропускаются, если вставляются вручную.

Comment: делайте запросы через `PDO` - он встроен в пхп, и проблем не будет таких и от инъекций защититесь. запросы в таком чистом виде (как у вас) - нельзя использовать, а можно только в ОЧЕНЬ определенных случаях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (count($data)) {

    $i = time();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_id`, `created`, `type`, `pair`, `price`, `quantity`, `amount`, `block_id`, `status`) VALUES ";

    foreach ($data as $k => $value){
        if ($value[chek] == "on") {

            $i++;

            $type = $value['type'];
            $pair = $value['pair'];
            $price = $value['price'];
            $quantity = $value['quantity'];
            $summ = $value['summ'];
            $block_id = $value['block_id'];
            $order_status = $value['order_status'];

            $sql .= "('$i', '$i', '$type', '$pair', '$price', '$quantity', '$summ', '$block_id', '$order_status'),";
        }
    }

    $final_sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);

    mysqli_query($conn, $final_sql);

}
```

В phpmyadmin можно вставлять несколько запросов через ";" 
Настоятельно рекомендую прислушаться к совету про PDO